# Javascript Library for Dynamic HTML Table Generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been looking around for a nice javascript library to dynamically create html tables. There are quite a few javascript-tools out there to "beatuify" and "functionalise" an existing table, this is only partly what I am after.

What I am looking for is a library that I can use to create nice looking tables, without having to first "manually" generate the table and then use the beautification tool. Much like the ones that exists for creating graphs; [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), [Flotr2](http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/) etc.

Does there exist such a library to allow me to simply pass a JSON-object or call a series of functions to generate a nice looking, sortable, functional HTML-table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is DataTables.js.

Goto this link and get started.  Enjoy.

http://datatables.net/

Comment: Datatables supports both static tables and AJAX-driven tables. It's a good choice.

Comment: I have quickly looked at this before, but seemed to have missed the functionality to create the tables from this as well. Thanks!

Comment: You're absolutely welcome.

Answer (score 3):

you can use use -

> jquery.dataTables.js, TableTools.js and dataTables.editor.js

with couple of css library which will give you option to generate beatiful data table. please have a look at below link

https://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/

which gives you details with example about the library.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [JSON-to-HTML Table](https://github.com/afshinm/Json-to-HTML-Table) on GitHub

To convert the object to a table, you can do

```
var jsonHtmlTable = ConvertJsonToTable(obj, 'jsonTable', null, 'Download');
```