# JSON data to multiple html tables

Tags: javascript, html, json

i'm trying to take some JSON data and create mutliple HTML tables.

Finding a lot of info about creating dynamic table columns, but not about creating dynamic tables eg. http://www.encodedna.com/javascript/populate-json-data-to-html-table-using-javascript.htm

how to take this json data & create a separate table for ***each*** "LOCATION", ***then*** populate tables with data?

```
    [
{"ID":"7767544","LAST_NAME":"fdafa","FIRST_NAME":"Thomas","MODAL":"GENERAL ","LOCATION":"3E","STATUS":"Ordered"},
{"ID":"56345634","LAST_NAME":"fsdadadf","FIRST_NAME":"John","MODAL":"ULTRASOUND","LOCATION":"2D","STATUS":"Active"},
{"ID":"867586","LAST_NAME":"brbtr","FIRST_NAME":"William","MODAL":"THEATRE ","LOCATION":"3E","STATUS":"Active"},
{"ID":"654363456","LAST_NAME":"bjcvb","FIRST_NAME":"Frank","MODAL":"CT ","LOCATION":"EU","STATUS":"Active"},
{"ID":"2542543","LAST_NAME":"cvzx","FIRST_NAME":"Gur","MODAL":"GENERAL ","LOCATION":"1W","STATUS":"Ordered"},
{"ID":"4765454","LAST_NAME":"kluiu","FIRST_NAME":"Helen ","MODAL":"GENERAL ","LOCATION":"1W","STATUS":"Ordered"},
{"ID":"747564","LAST_NAME":"ertewr","FIRST_NAME":"Ingeborg","MODAL":"GENERAL ","LOCATION":"3B","STATUS":"Active"},
{"ID":"8798565","LAST_NAME":"gfhdgf","FIRST_NAME":"Elizabeth","MODAL":"GENERAL ","LOCATION":"1W","STATUS":"Ordered"},
{"ID":"9585676","LAST_NAME":"kjhkhj","FIRST_NAME":"John","MODAL":"ULTRASOUND","LOCATION":"3E","STATUS":"Pending"}
]
```

to look like this.....

```
    <table id="location_3E">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>LAST_NAME</th><th>FIRSTNAME</th><th>MODAL</th></tr>
<tr><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="location_2D">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>LAST_NAME</th><th>FIRSTNAME</th><th>MODAL</th></tr>
<tr><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="location_EU">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>LAST_NAME</th><th>FIRSTNAME</th><th>MODAL</th></tr>
<tr><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="location_1W">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>LAST_NAME</th><th>FIRSTNAME</th><th>MODAL</th></tr>
<tr><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="location_3B">
<tr>
<th>ID</th><th>LAST_NAME</th><th>FIRSTNAME</th><th>MODAL</th></tr>
<tr><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td><td>*somedata*</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is one reason Framework are around these days. I dont know your situation but angular, react etc. Make it easier to combine Json/JavaScript and HTML

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like a **Templating engine** if you have json data which you want to display in html.

A good example would be to use **jsrender**, you can check out https://jsfiddle.net/bux2gj1m/

```
var obj = [
{"ID":"7767544","LAST_NAME":"fdafa","FIRST_NAME":"Thomas","MODAL":"GENERAL ","LOCATION":"3E","STATUS":"Ordered"},
{"ID":"56345634","LAST_NAME":"fsdadadf","FIRST_NAME":"John","MODAL":"ULTRASOUND","LOCATION":"2D","STATUS":"Active"},
{"ID":"867586","LAST_NAME":"brbtr","FIRST_NAME":"William","MODAL":"THEATRE ","LOCATION":"3E","STATUS":"Active"},
{"ID":"654363456","LAST_NAME":"bjcvb","FIRST_NAME":"Frank","MODAL":"CT ","LOCATION":"EU","STATUS":"Active"},
{"ID":"2542543","LAST_NAME":"cvzx","FIRST_NAME":"Gur","MODAL":"GENERAL ","LOCATION":"1W","STATUS":"Ordered"},
{"ID":"4765454","LAST_NAME":"kluiu","FIRST_NAME":"Helen ","MODAL":"GENERAL ","LOCATION":"1W","STATUS":"Ordered"},
{"ID":"747564","LAST_NAME":"ertewr","FIRST_NAME":"Ingeborg","MODAL":"GENERAL ","LOCATION":"3B","STATUS":"Active"},
{"ID":"8798565","LAST_NAME":"gfhdgf","FIRST_NAME":"Elizabeth","MODAL":"GENERAL ","LOCATION":"1W","STATUS":"Ordered"},
{"ID":"9585676","LAST_NAME":"kjhkhj","FIRST_NAME":"John","MODAL":"ULTRASOUND","LOCATION":"3E","STATUS":"Pending"}
];

var myTmpl = $.templates("#random");
var htmlop = myTmpl.render(obj);
// $("#display").html(html);
$("#demo").html(htmlop);
```

You can render inside a html block such as:

```
</div>
<script id="random" type="text/x-jsrender">
 <table id="location_{{:Location}}">
  <tr>
    <th>{{:ID}}</th><th>LAST_NAME</th>
    <th>{{:FIRST_NAME}}</th><th>MODAL</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*somedata*</td>
    <td>*somedata*</td>
    <td>*somedata*</td>
    <td>*somedata*</td>         
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of libraries out there specially made for dynamically generating tables [Javascript Library for Dynamic HTML Table Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21188965/2333214) which include features like seartching, sorting, pagination etc.
Nowadays there are template engines, libraries having data binding etc.

It's better to not reinvent the wheel, But if your use case is as simple as you mentioned in question you can try the following code without having to import any additional functionalities:

```js
var locations = [{
  "ID": "7767544",
  "LAST_NAME": "fdafa",
  "FIRST_NAME": "Thomas",
  "MODAL": "GENERAL ",
  "LOCATION": "3E",
  "STATUS": "Ordered"
}, {
  "ID": "56345634",
  "LAST_NAME": "fsdadadf",
  "FIRST_NAME": "John",
  "MODAL": "ULTRASOUND",
  "LOCATION": "2D",
  "STATUS": "Active"
}, {
  "ID": "867586",
  "LAST_NAME": "brbtr",
  "FIRST_NAME": "William",
  "MODAL": "THEATRE ",
  "LOCATION": "3E",
  "STATUS": "Active"
}, {
  "ID": "654363456",
  "LAST_NAME": "bjcvb",
  "FIRST_NAME": "Frank",
  "MODAL": "CT ",
  "LOCATION": "EU",
  "STATUS": "Active"
}, {
  "ID": "2542543",
  "LAST_NAME": "cvzx",
  "FIRST_NAME": "Gur",
  "MODAL": "GENERAL ",
  "LOCATION": "1W",
  "STATUS": "Ordered"
}, {
  "ID": "4765454",
  "LAST_NAME": "kluiu",
  "FIRST_NAME": "Helen ",
  "MODAL": "GENERAL ",
  "LOCATION": "1W",
  "STATUS": "Ordered"
}, {
  "ID": "747564",
  "LAST_NAME": "ertewr",
  "FIRST_NAME": "Ingeborg",
  "MODAL": "GENERAL ",
  "LOCATION": "3B",
  "STATUS": "Active"
}, {
  "ID": "8798565",
  "LAST_NAME": "gfhdgf",
  "FIRST_NAME": "Elizabeth",
  "MODAL": "GENERAL ",
  "LOCATION": "1W",
  "STATUS": "Ordered"
}, {
  "ID": "9585676",
  "LAST_NAME": "kjhkhj",
  "FIRST_NAME": "John",
  "MODAL": "ULTRASOUND",
  "LOCATION": "3E",
  "STATUS": "Pending"
}]
var body = document.body;
locations.forEach(function(location) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var keys = Object.keys(location);
  var values = [];
  var thead = document.createElement('thead');
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    values.push(location[key]); // avoid another loop to find values
    var th = document.createElement('th');
    th.textContent = key;
    thead.appendChild(th);
  });
  table.appendChild(thead);
  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  values.forEach(function(val) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.textContent = val;
    tr.appendChild(td);
  });
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
  body.appendChild(table);
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
table thead {
  background: #ebebeb;
}
table thead th {
  font-weight: normal;
}
table tbody {
  background: lightblue;
}
table td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use any existing template engine. There are plenty of there already from which you can choose one. I would suggest **[HandlebarsJS](http://handlebarsjs.com/)** as this is most popular in all of them out there.

You can find the documentation there on the website too for it.

Coming to your problem, you want to create a table with dynamic data which has `n` number or rows and `m` number of columns. In case number of columns are not defined, you will need to iterate again for each row, otherwise you can print the data based on the column known.

Here is an example of doing that. See [this workin plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/AoV6JG2IFKb4FfRoqsY3?p=preview).

Handlbars Template is as below:

```
<script id="grid-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table>
      <thead> 
        {{#if data.length}}
          <tr>
            {{#each data.[0]}}
            <th>{{@key}}</th>
            {{/each}}
          </tr>
        {{/if}}
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each data}}
          <tr>
            {{#each this}}
            <td>{{@this}}</td>
            {{/each}}
          </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </script>
```

Very small JS will be required if you use template engines. Here is my example:

```
var grid = {
    data: tableData // coming from data.js
  };

  // Compiling Handlebars tempalte
  var gridTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#grid-template").html());

  // Rendering Grid data in to HTML
  $("#grid-container").html(gridTemplate(grid));
```

[Try this working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/AoV6JG2IFKb4FfRoqsY3?p=preview)