# JSON data to multiple html tables within a 2-column layout grid

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

My requirement is somewhat similar to [JSON data to multiple html tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37476194/json-data-to-multiple-html-tables)

I have a JSON file that needs to be rendered into multiple tables. Each table is a 2 column table (essentially name-value format).  I have come up with the following script to do that.  It works as expected.

```
function jsonToMultipleTables(jsonData) {
  var body = document.body;
  jsonData.forEach(function(tuple) {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    table.innerHTML = "blah blah blah caption";

    var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    var keys = Object.keys(tuple);
    var values = [];
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');
      values.push(tuple[key]);
      var td1 = document.createElement('td');
      td1.textContent = key;
      tr.appendChild(td1);
      var td2 = document.createElement('td');
      td2.textContent = tuple[key];
      tr.appendChild(td2);
      tbody.appendChild(tr);
    });
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    body.appendChild(table);

    document.write("<br/>");
  });
}
```

For a more aesthetic feel, I would like the tables to be laid out within a 2-column layout grid for the page.  Any suggestions on how to go about that?

Comment: You could make the tables 50% width and have them float to the left.

Comment: I tried the approach suggested in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_two_columns.asp but it does not work.Basically I tried to create my tables within a "div" element whose class is set to "column".  The column has 50% width and it floats to the left.